# Sum first 20 rows in grouped items

Tags: mysql, sum, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table named iran_ranking like:

| user_id | user_state | point_year | user_point | user_sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tehran | 2022 | 200 | men |
| 2 | Tehran | 2021 | 200 | men |
| 3 | Ahwaz | 2020 | 190 | men |
| 1 | Tehran | 2022 | 180 | men |
| 3 | Ahwaz | 2022 | 170 | men |

I want to sum all user_point of user_id like this:

```
user_id 1 = 380,
user_id 2 = 200,
user_id 3 = 360,
```

I reach the first goal with this statement:

```sql
SELECT *,
SUM(user_point) AS pointsum
from iran_ranking 
where user_sex = 'men' AND point_year > 2019
group by user_id";
```

Now, I need to get sum of first 20 player of Tehran & Ahwaz like this:

```
Tehran = 580
Ahwaz = 360
```

I tried SELECT TOP(20) and gave me error, I also tried LIMIT 20, but it limited first 20 of all rows not first 20 of Tehran and first 20 of Ahwaz.

Comment: You have already got the data about separate users. Now you'd enumerate them over user_state, then aggregate the rows which have the number not greater than 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *,
       SUM(pointsum) AS pointsum_top20
FROM (
    SELECT user_state,
           SUM(user_point) AS pointsum,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_state ORDER BY SUM(user_point) DESC) rn
    FROM iran_ranking 
    -- WHERE ...
    GROUP BY user_id, user_state
    ) subquery
WHERE rn <= 20
GROUP BY user_state
```

Comment: Thank you Akina for your time and edit. but it didn't work it gives me bool error!

Comment: @rezarezakhani Always provide complete text of error message.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on bool in...

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on bool in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wp-content/themes/betheme-child/inc/overall-ranking/overall-create.php:31 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wp-content/themes/betheme-

Comment: @rezarezakhani This is not MySQL-side problem. Debug your PHP code.

Comment: i think the query return bool thats why php cant parse it.

Comment: i found it. your answer is correct but need edit. there is a comma after pointsum_top20 that not should be.